# missing 3 required positional arguments: 'self', 'to', and 'messages'

Tags: python, selenium

#### What I want to do

Get information from a portal site and push it to my LINE app on my phone.

#### Error

```
TypeError: push_message() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'self', 'to', and 'messages'
```

#### Source code

The process of getting information with Selenium seems to be working well, so it is omitted.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pyautogui as auto
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from linebot.models import TextSendMessage
from linebot.exceptions import LineBotApiError

ID = ''
PASS = ''

from linebot import LineBotApi
from linebot.models import TextSendMessage

LINE_CHANNEL_ACCESS_TOKEN=''



def main():
    main = 'test'
    user_id = ""
    send=LineBotApi.push_message()
    send(to=user_id, messages=TextSendMessage(text=main))

main()
```

#### What I have tried

I have added `def main():`, but still it does not solve the problem.

#### Additional information

I am new to Python and programming.

Comment: I think the message tells you to pass `to` and `messages` arguments to the function. `push_message(to=something, message=something)`

Comment: you need to pass the mentioned arguments while calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    line_bot_api.push_message('<to>', TextSendMessage(text='Hello World!'))
except LineBotApiError as e:
    # error handle
```

For more information:

https://developers.line.biz/en/reference/messaging-api/#send-push-message

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried this and got `TypeError: push_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'messages'
`.   Are there anything I can do something different?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pyautogui as auto
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from linebot.models import TextSendMessage
from linebot.exceptions import LineBotApiError

ID = ''
PASS = ''

from linebot import LineBotApi
from linebot.models import TextSendMessage

LINE_CHANNEL_ACCESS_TOKEN=''



def main():
    main_text = 'test'
    user_id = ""
    send=LineBotApi().push_message(to=user_id,    message=TextSendMessage(text=main_text))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried this and got `TypeError: push_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
`

Comment: I replaced 'message=' with 'messages' and tried but resulted `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'channel_access_token'
`